# How to generate 50 page PDF document dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ssrs-2012

I need to generate 50 page PDF document dynamically. Mainly these are different application form. Data are present in database and those will bind in PDF dynamically. What is the best way to create template and generate PDF? I have sample PDF, I need to create template as per sample PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You may generate the html template for the document dynamically and use headlesschrome to generate the pdf from the html. Here's a good library that does conversion to pdf:
[Converts any URL or HTML content to a PDF file](https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api)

It uses headlesschrome for rendering pdf.

You may also use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) alternatively, but that has its own limitation for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There are also plenty of PDF generation tools out there that can help you with this.

As an example, this .Net Developer writes in an IT Central Station review that he uses Windward Studios for this exact use case. He writes that one major valuable feature is, "creating dynamic table of contents (TOC) based on dynamic data in different reports. We have different reports generated by users. After generating the report, the user will modify it and add some pages to it...In all other reporting tools, the table of contents is generated based on bookmarks of everything the user wants in the TOC. That means page numbers in the TOC generate at runtime and, if you modify the report, you can’t update the TOC. But AutoTag, follows same tags as Microsoft Word, and you can update the TOC any time after generating your report." You can read the rest of his review [here](https://www.itcentralstation.com/product_reviews/windward-studios-review-49275-by-haleh-mehrabadi/tzd/c582-sf-90) to learn more about his experience with this tool.

I hope this is helpful, and good luck with your search.